# [1]: max virtual memory areas vm.max_map_count [65530] is too low, increase to at least [262144] - Not working even after changing sysctl.conf file

Tags: elasticsearch, docker-compose

I changed /etc/sysctl.conf file and added statement `vm.max_map_count=262144`, restarted laptop and still the same error keeps occurring whenever I execute: `docker-compose -f docker-amundsen.yml up` on terminal.

Can anyone please suggest some solution?

[image]

EDIT: Solved now.

Comment: I've come across it but have forgotten how to solve it... Have you tried ```sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.conf/``` ?

Comment: Yes @Johnny , I tried that also, But still not working.

Comment: Are you modify ```/etc/sysctl.conf``` file ?

Comment: Yes, I added statement added statement `vm.max_map_count=262144` in /etc/sysctl.conf file.

Comment: try ```sudo sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144```

Comment: Tried that also! :(

Comment: Are you use wsl?

Comment: No, I am using ubuntu

Comment: Please note it down if it is resolved. Thanks !

Comment: The actual issue was : docker-machine added a layer of virtualization which kept vm.max_map_count = 65530 even if I would change in my OS.

Answer (score 2):

To make it persistent, you can add this line:

```
$ sudo nano /etc/sysctl.conf
```

vm.max_map_count=262144

```
$ sudo sysctl -p
```